# Why is this python for range loop not working?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

Simple prime function. The loop does not run when `x < 2`. I don't quite understand why. Can someone explain? I understand my starting range is 2, but that is only for `i`; why should that affect `x`?

Thank you.

```
def is_prime (x):
    for i in range(2, x-1, 1):
        if (x % i == 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Thank you everyone. Gosh, I can't believe how I overlooked the max range call.

Comment: Note: you don't need the extra argument `1`; the step defaults to that value.

Comment: Because your range is 2..x-1, when x < 2 your range is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(lower_bound, upper_bound, step)` produces a sequence of numbers that start at `lower_bound` and increment by `step` until `upper_bound` is reached. In your case, when x = 1, `range(2,x-1,1)` will produce an empty sequence because your lower bound is greater than your upper bound, but your step is positive. In other words, there is no sequence that starts at 2 and ends at 0  (x-1) but increases by 1.

You wrote your for loop with the assumption that the number being passed to it will be 2 or greater. You may need to add "base case" scenarios when the argument is less than 2.

Comment: `upper_bound` is not included in the output. It's upper_bound-1.

Answer (score 1):

You are letting `i` run over the range of integers `2, 3, 4, ..., x-1`. When `x < 2`, the range is empty, and the loop is never entered (so the loop body will not be executed at all).

Actually, for what it's worth, the loop is empty when `x <= 3`. This is because python's `range(A, B)` will be a range of integers `n` such that `A <= n < B`. Note the strict inequality on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over an empty sequence results in no iterations.

```
>>> range(2, 1, 1)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what `i` is going to loop through:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> range(2, x-1, 1)
[]
```

It's an *empty* array! There's nothing to be done here.